# 07:40:24:023 FATAL_ERROR System.StringException: Invalid id: a610V0000015C5DQAU

Tags: visualforce, controller, class, salesforce-id

```java
public void updateattendeecb() {
    System.debug(enteredText1);
    Id myId = Id.valueOf(enteredText1);
    list_attendees1=[Select id,Send_Email_for_Certificate__c from EM_Attendee_vod__c where id= :myId];
    //  list_attendees1=Database.query('Select Id, Send_Email_for_Certificate__c from EM_Attendee_vod__c where Id='+attendee_id);
    if(!list_attendees1[0].Send_Email_for_Certificate__c) {
        list_attendees1[0].Send_Email_for_Certificate__c=true;
        update list_attendees1;    
    }
}
```

So the line
`Id myId = Id.valueOf(enteredText1);` 
is causing the above error.

I used `system.debug(enteredText1)` and it's showing correct id value in string. Now I am trying to convert to Id return type but getting the error. The variable **enteredText1** is returning the correct value

```java
07:40:24:023 USER_DEBUG [20]|DEBUG|a610V0000015C5DQAU.
```

This id is fine but don't know the error here. Please help.

Comment: May be you can try by using first 15 characters.

Comment: Is there whitespace, or other non-printing unicode characters at the end (or start?) of the string?

Comment: Agreed with @ca_peterson. Looks like there is a period at the end of the Id. I ran a system debug for an Id and there was no period at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work when attempted independnetly, using execute anonymous via the sfdx CLI for example:

```
>> Start typing Apex code. Press the Enter key after each line, 
>> then press CTRL+D when finished.
> String enteredText1 = 'a610V0000015C5DQAU';
Id myId = Id.valueOf(enteredText1);
> System.debug(myId);
Compiled successfully.
Executed successfully.

49.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO
Execute Anonymous: String enteredText1 = 'a610V0000015C5DQAU';
Execute Anonymous: Id myId = Id.valueOf(enteredText1);
Execute Anonymous: System.debug(myId);
21:05:55.41 (41527237)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|0059A000002vILv|test-brmv1q3myzqi@example.com|(GMT-07:00) Pacific Daylight Time (America/Los_Angeles)|GMT-07:00
21:05:55.41 (41562129)|EXECUTION_STARTED
21:05:55.41 (41570907)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
21:05:55.41 (42463391)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|a610V0000015C5DQAU
21:05:55.42 (42595094)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
21:05:55.42 (42595094)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

21:05:55.42 (42595094)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

21:05:55.41 (42676157)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|execute_anonymous_apex
21:05:55.41 (42688967)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

From that, I have to assume there is whitespace, or other non-printing characters in your `enteredText` variable. Can you check its length? use .trim() before you assign it to an ID?